# Rotation of image in OpenLayers 3.0

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Because of Google Earth's deprecation of their plug-in, I need to rotate an image overlaid atop a tiled OpenLayers 3.0 layer, but don't see any way to do this.

I'm layering historic maps on the map, and not all of them face north.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with an `ol.layer.Image` layer and `ol.source.ImageCanvas` source? I imagine that the `canvasFunction` could create a canvas and use `context.rotate` and `context.drawImage` to draw a rotated image into the canvas.

Comment: I've thought about that, but then I have to manage the extent by hand in pixels, rather than specifying a lat/lon.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution?

I'm facing the same and I still haven't tried it, but as far as I've read it looks like a Vector Layer with a point feature could do the trick if we define a style function to keep bearing and scale.

[Make marker zoom/rotate with map in Openlayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870301/make-marker-zoom-rotate-with-map-in-openlayers-3)

```
vectorLayer.setStyle(function(feature, resolution) {
  var maxResolution = 10000;
  var styleArray = [ new ol.style.Style( {
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      src: 'http://your.path.to/the/image.png',
      scale: maxResolution/resolution,
      rotateWithView: true,
      rotation: .5,
      anchor: [.5,.5],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction', anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      opacity: 0.75
    })
  })];
  return styleArray;
});
```

Comment: We ended up adding the images to a canvas layer