# Make marker zoom/rotate with map in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to overlay an image over an OpenLayers 3.0 map by adding a point feature to the layer, and setting the icon to the image to load. How can I get it to scale with the map as it is being zoomed?
Or is there a better way to overlay an image atop a layer?

```
p=ol.proj.transform( [-78,40],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')
var f=new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.Point(p) });

var imgStyle=new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        rotateWithView: false,
        anchor: [.5,.5],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction', anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: 'http://www.viseyes.org/shiva/map.jpg'
        }))
    });

f.setStyle(imgStyle);
myLayerr.getSource().addFeature(f);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use an [image of a map](http://www.viseyes.org/shiva/map.jpg) as an overlay.  Instead of using the image as an icon for a feature with a point geometry, you'd be better off using an image layer with a [static image source](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.ImageStatic.html).  See the code below for an example (also http://jsfiddle.net/tschaub/orr6qfkc/).

```js
var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(
    [-5.6342, 50.3331, 1.6607, 53.0559], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'http://www.viseyes.org/shiva/map.jpg',
        imageExtent: extent
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 7
  })
});
```

I've just guessed at the geographic extent of the image.  It may also be that the image overlays better on a map with the view projection set to [`'EPSG:4326'`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/epsg-4326.html).

Note that if you want to use an icon to symbolize a point feature and you want it to rotate and scale with the map (as the title of this question implies), you need to do two things:

- Set the `rotateWithView` option to `true` (the default of `false` means that the icon will not rotate when you rotate the map).
- Give your vector layer a style function.  This function will be called with your feature and the view resolution.  You can then scale your icon using the resolution.  The style function below should give you a rough idea of how this could work.

```js
// resolution at which to display the
// icon at 1:1
var maxResolution = 10000;

function style(feature, resolution) {
  var icon = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      src: 'http://example.com/icon.png',
      scale: maxResolution / resolution,
      rotateWithView: true
    }))
  });
  return [symbolizer];
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work if I added imageSize: [1176,724] to the Icon{}, but I'm at a loss as to the relationship of that an the extent. Do you know of any clear documentation on InageStatic options?

Comment: The [`imageExtent`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.ImageStatic.html) option for the `ol.source.ImageStatic` is the extent of the image in the coordinate reference system of your map's view.  By default, map views are in the Web Mercator projection, with units in meters.  As shown in my first example above, if you know the extent of the image in geographic coordinates (min lon, min lat, max lon, max lat), you can transform this into an extent in your view projection with the `ol.proj.transformExtent` function.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to rotate an imageStatic layer? Thanks for all your help here.

Comment: The `ol.source.ImageStatic` assumes that the image is aligned with the coordinate reference system (e.g. north is up).  While it could make sense to add support for image rotation, a more general solution would involve support for arbitrary transforms between the source and view projections (i.e. warping the image during rendering).  I don't know of any work underway to add this type of functionality.

Comment: We solved the issue by adding images via the canvasLayer. A little inelegant, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim's help, I was able to rotate image markers that scale with the view. Max

Here's the final code :

```
var p=ol.proj.transform( [-78,40],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')
var f=new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.Point(p) });
this.boxLayer.getSource().addFeature(f);                        

this.boxLayer.setStyle(function(feature, resolution) {
    var styleArray = [ new ol.style.Style( {
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'http://www.viseyes.org/shiva/map.jpg',
        scale: maxResolution/resolution,
        rotateWithView: true,
        rotation: .5,
        anchor: [.5,.5],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction', anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        opacity: 0.75
        })
     })];
     return styleArray;
});
```